# Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT for java -cp argument

Tags: java, docker, mysql-connector

I'm attempting to create a docker file for running a program that takes the mysqlconnector jar when I run it on gitbash:

`java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar test.java`

How do I translate this to the Dockerfile? I have attempted setting the ENTRYPOINT as the string above but get an error saying

`“Could Not Find or Load Main Class” Error test.java`

Comment: how does your Dockerfile look so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker does know anything about your needed dependencies.
You will need to move all your classes/3rd party jars into a common folder to mimic how you are doing it locally.

```
FROM openjdk:11

# Set up the Environment Variable for Application
ENV APP_HOME=/app

# Create the directories for Application
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}

# Setting up the Work directory
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Exposing the Application Port
EXPOSE 8080

# COPY dependencies
COPY /send-email-api/target/your-mysql-jars ${APP_HOME}

# Copying the artifact from host machine to containers
COPY /send-email-api/target/*classes ${APP_HOME}


ENTRYPOINT java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar test.java
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar","test.java"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Susan-mustafa! 


I have copied  all needed 3rd party jars into my WORK_DIR as per suggestion 3.

The main purpose of my Dockerfile is to run test.java. I have provided the  mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar as test.java utilizes it in the code.  

As per your suggestion, the ENTRYPOINT is set to the jar file, but I want to ENTRYPOINT to still invoke the java program and also include the jar file as a parameter. 

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to compile.

```
java test.java
```

will always fail, regardless whether you use a container or not. Compile it using

```
javac test.java
```

then you will see some test.class file (which somehow violates Java naming conventions but so what). Finally run this using

```
java test
```

(you omit the .class and Java will find it using the classpath)

Comment: I have already compiled. The program works completely fine outside of the docker environment, the issue is when I add it to the docker environment it throws this error.

Comment: Please doublecheck: When you run the code outside docker, do you really run test.java? It makes me suspicious...

Comment: After compilation outside docker, I run using ```java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar test.java```

Comment: Wondering whether that is an implicit compliation - have you tried to provide the source code in your docker file as well? In the container, do you have a JRE or a JDK?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe do you need the package's path, for example

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar my/package/test.java
```

And obviously this class must be have a main method

Comment: I haven't created a package name. It is a simple java file that uses the mysqlconnector jar in the program. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Is a maven or Ant project?

Comment: Its a basic java progam file. I have not used maven or Ant.