# Docker Compose NoClassDefFoundError while trying to run container. Not recoginizing JSON Dependency

Tags: java, json, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

Can someone please help me I'm trying to make a container from my java app. I'm using maven and it runs perfectly locally. But when I'm trying to run it as a container, i get this error. I already have the JSON dependency in my pom.xml but it's still not working.

This is the Error log:

```
Attaching to vs-lager
vs-lager    | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
vs-lager    |   at Main_lager.main(Main_lager.java:7)
vs-lager    | Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
vs-lager    |   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
vs-lager    |   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
vs-lager    |   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
vs-lager    |   ... 1 more
vs-lager exited with code 1
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 AS BUILD
#Kopiere alle Dateien
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
COPY src /tmp/src/
WORKDIR /tmp/

#Build .jar file
RUN mvn clean package

#Finaler Container
FROM openjdk:11

COPY --from=BUILD /tmp/target/vs-lager-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /tmp

CMD ["java", "-jar", "/tmp/vs-lager-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I already have this dependency instead of my pom.xml file
pom.xml:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: As I have a feeling this is not a Springboot fat jar, it most likely means (Whatever jars you actually need, are not included).   You need to include them in your dockerFile and therefore in your container, Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69346446/dockerfile-entrypoint-for-java-cp-argument/69346818#69346818

Comment: @SMA thank you for pointing our the problem! managed to solve the problem with creating a fat jarfile using maven shade plugin

Comment: anytime, glad you got it working.